# Saving Image Rather Than Pasting

Tags: graphics, errors, copy-paste

I think I might have accidentally pressed some combination of keys that messed up texstudio, because every time of press ctrl+v to paste it saves a picture file rather than paste.

What did I do wrong?

**EDIT**

Here is precisely what pops up when I press ctrl+v:

[image]

Comment: I didn't realize how frequently I used ctrl+v until now...This is excruciating, especially since I am dealing with matrices in latex...It's only been five minutes and I miss ctrl+v...

Comment: Have you tried closing the application and reopening it? (Wish I could be more help, but in [my editor](https://xkcd.com/378/) 'ctrl+v' for me does a 'page down'....)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please go to TeXstudio’s preferences and then in section “short cuts” (I guess – I have the german version) check wether the short cut for past is set correctly if not, you can change it there.

However I’m think TeXstudio isn’t capable of taking screenshots anyway, so I assume that there is another program which has crtl+v assigned as a system wide shortcut? Does ctrl+v work in other applications?